# kml of geotag photos not displaying in mymaps in google maps

Tags: google-maps, gis, kml

I've used a python application "exif2kml.py" from google which pretty much creates a kml file of your pic, and when I uploaded to mymaps in google is not showing up. do you guys know if google support the displaying of kml files in maps, or do I need to use any other application?

here's the kml file

```
<code>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document>
    <PhotoOverlay id="photo0">
      <name>pix/IMG_20150317_161004.jpg</name>
      <description>
<![CDATA[<a href="#photo0">Click here to fly into photo</a>]]>      </description>
      <Camera>
        <longitude>-80.3107299722</longitude>
        <latitude>25.9407806389</latitude>
        <altitude>10</altitude>
        <tilt>90</tilt>
      </Camera>
      <Icon>
        <href>pix/IMG_20150317_161004.jpg</href>
      </Icon>
      <ViewVolume>
        <leftFov>-26.6666666667</leftFov>
        <rightFov>26.6666666667</rightFov>
        <bottomFov>-20</bottomFov>
        <topFov>20</topFov>
        <near>10</near>
      </ViewVolume>
      <point>
        <coordinates>-80.3107299722,25.9407806389,48</coordinates>
      </point>
    </PhotoOverlay>
    <PhotoOverlay id="photo1">
      <name>pix/IMG_20150317_160824.jpg</name>
      <description>
<![CDATA[<a href="#photo1">Click here to fly into photo</a>]]>      </description>
      <Camera>
        <longitude>-80.3077468611</longitude>
        <latitude>25.9396915278</latitude>
        <altitude>10</altitude>
        <tilt>90</tilt>
      </Camera>
      <Icon>
        <href>pix/IMG_20150317_160824.jpg</href>
      </Icon>
      <ViewVolume>
        <leftFov>-26.6666666667</leftFov>
        <rightFov>26.6666666667</rightFov>
        <bottomFov>-20</bottomFov>
        <topFov>20</topFov>
        <near>10</near>
      </ViewVolume>
      <point>
        <coordinates>-80.3077468611,25.9396915278,0</coordinates>
      </point>
    </PhotoOverlay>
    <PhotoOverlay id="photo2">
      <name>pix/IMG_20150317_184109.jpg</name>
      <description>
<![CDATA[<a href="#photo2">Click here to fly into photo</a>]]>      </description>
      <Camera>
        <longitude>-80.3423843333</longitude>
        <latitude>25.9427413889</latitude>
        <altitude>10</altitude>
        <tilt>90</tilt>
      </Camera>
      <Icon>
        <href>pix/IMG_20150317_184109.jpg</href>
      </Icon>
      <ViewVolume>
        <leftFov>-26.6666666667</leftFov>
        <rightFov>26.6666666667</rightFov>
        <bottomFov>-20</bottomFov>
        <topFov>20</topFov>
        <near>10</near>
      </ViewVolume>
      <point>
        <coordinates>-80.3423843333,25.9427413889,4294967295</coordinates>
      </point>
    </PhotoOverlay>
    <PhotoOverlay id="photo3">
      <name>pix/IMG_20150317_164728.jpg</name>
      <description>
<![CDATA[<a href="#photo3">Click here to fly into photo</a>]]>      </description>
      <Camera>
        <longitude>-80.3147048889</longitude>
        <latitude>25.9369277778</latitude>
        <altitude>10</altitude>
        <tilt>90</tilt>
      </Camera>
      <Icon>
        <href>pix/IMG_20150317_164728.jpg</href>
      </Icon>
      <ViewVolume>
        <leftFov>-15.0</leftFov>
        <rightFov>15.0</rightFov>
        <bottomFov>-20</bottomFov>
        <topFov>20</topFov>
        <near>10</near>
      </ViewVolume>
      <point>
        <coordinates>-80.3147048889,25.9369277778,11</coordinates>
      </point>
    </PhotoOverlay>
    <PhotoOverlay id="photo4">
      <name>pix/IMG_20150317_164738.jpg</name>
      <description>
<![CDATA[<a href="#photo4">Click here to fly into photo</a>]]>      </description>
      <Camera>
        <longitude>-80.3147201389</longitude>
        <latitude>25.9370803611</latitude>
        <altitude>10</altitude>
        <tilt>90</tilt>
      </Camera>
      <Icon>
        <href>pix/IMG_20150317_164738.jpg</href>
      </Icon>
      <ViewVolume>
        <leftFov>-15.0</leftFov>
        <rightFov>15.0</rightFov>
        <bottomFov>-20</bottomFov>
        <topFov>20</topFov>
        <near>10</near>
      </ViewVolume>
      <point>
        <coordinates>-80.3147201389,25.9370803611,4294967293</coordinates>
      </point>
    </PhotoOverlay>
    <PhotoOverlay id="photo5">
      <name>pix/IMG_20150317_161721.jpg</name>
      <description>
<![CDATA[<a href="#photo5">Click here to fly into photo</a>]]>      </description>
      <Camera>
        <longitude>-80.3132476667</longitude>
        <latitude>25.935894</latitude>
        <altitude>10</altitude>
        <tilt>90</tilt>
      </Camera>
      <Icon>
        <href>pix/IMG_20150317_161721.jpg</href>
      </Icon>
      <ViewVolume>
        <leftFov>-26.6666666667</leftFov>
        <rightFov>26.6666666667</rightFov>
        <bottomFov>-20</bottomFov>
        <topFov>20</topFov>
        <near>10</near>
      </ViewVolume>
      <point>
        <coordinates>-80.3132476667,25.935894,4294967289</coordinates>
      </point>
    </PhotoOverlay>
    <PhotoOverlay id="photo6">
      <name>pix/IMG_20150317_161712.jpg</name>
      <description>
<![CDATA[<a href="#photo6">Click here to fly into photo</a>]]>      </description>
      <Camera>
        <longitude>-80.3132247778</longitude>
        <latitude>25.9359016389</latitude>
        <altitude>10</altitude>
        <tilt>90</tilt>
      </Camera>
      <Icon>
        <href>pix/IMG_20150317_161712.jpg</href>
      </Icon>
      <ViewVolume>
        <leftFov>-26.6666666667</leftFov>
        <rightFov>26.6666666667</rightFov>
        <bottomFov>-20</bottomFov>
        <topFov>20</topFov>
        <near>10</near>
      </ViewVolume>
      <point>
        <coordinates>-80.3132247778,25.9359016389,4294967289</coordinates>
      </point>
    </PhotoOverlay>
    <PhotoOverlay id="photo7">
      <name>pix/IMG_20150317_161734.jpg</name>
      <description>
<![CDATA[<a href="#photo7">Click here to fly into photo</a>]]>      </description>
      <Camera>
        <longitude>-80.3132476667</longitude>
        <latitude>25.935894</latitude>
        <altitude>10</altitude>
        <tilt>90</tilt>
      </Camera>
      <Icon>
        <href>pix/IMG_20150317_161734.jpg</href>
      </Icon>
      <ViewVolume>
        <leftFov>-26.6666666667</leftFov>
        <rightFov>26.6666666667</rightFov>
        <bottomFov>-20</bottomFov>
        <topFov>20</topFov>
        <near>10</near>
      </ViewVolume>
      <point>
        <coordinates>-80.3132476667,25.935894,4294967289</coordinates>
      </point>
    </PhotoOverlay>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

Comment: Check this out: https://developers.google.com/maps/support/kmlmaps

Answer (score 0):

`PhotoOverlay` and `Camera` are [not supported in KML for Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlelementsinmaps)